# Node.js With Apache , Proxy Error : The proxy server could not handle the request Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Tags: node.js, apache, server, cpanel

[image]I am using node.js with Apache . We Apply SSL On eideabox.com by CPanel ,but without ssl working fine but with SSL is not working.

Below we mentions node code and config file code ,
below mention error massege
PrProxy Error : The proxy server could not handle the request Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote serveroxy Error : The proxy server could not handle the request Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

config file apache

```
<VirtualHost 132.148.158.82:443>
    ServerName eideabox.com
    ServerAlias www.eideabox.com
    DocumentRoot /home/eideabox/myapp/
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 503 /check.html

    ProxyPass /check.html !
    ProxyPass / https://eideabox.com:3006
    ProxyPassReverse / https://eideabox.com:3006
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off


    SSLCertificateFile /home/eideabox/ssl/certs/eideabox_com_b197e_c6311_1612597094_7e97c1d74286789f7015a7f48eafcfe0.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/eideabox/ssl/keys/b197e_c6311_43b35dcc21272dfd87cddf03acbf9dc7.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/eideabox/ssl/certs/eideabox_com_b197e_c6311_1612597094_7e97c1d74286789f7015a7f48eafcfe0.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find solution:

Probably your nodejs server don't have ssl config, so need to use 'http':
ProxyPass / http://eideabox.com:3006

In case you config ssl in you nodejs server (using require('https')) , you could use 'https':
ProxyPass / https://eideabox.com:3006

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve your code block formatting. See [answer]